# Test for comparing graphs of daily activity

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I need to compare some (or a least two) graphs of activity of  birds, like in the example below.
Column “Hour” –  it’s a time  (8.25 = 8 h 15 min, 8.50 = 8h 30 min, 8.75 = 8h 45 min, etc; 
column R –  it’s a mean number of birds that were observed at this time in a month.

What statistical test I can use for compare these curves with each other? By dint of this test I want to obtain answer: Do these graphs have a statistically significant difference?

```
> A                     B                       C   
> Hours R(January)      Hours   R(July)         Hours   R(September)
> 8.25  0.00            8.25    0.00            8.25    0.00
> 8.50  0.00            8.50    0.00            8.50    1.38
> 8.75  0.00            8.75    0.00            8.75    2.23
> 9.00  3.75            9.00    0.11            9.00    4.15
> 9.25  1.54            9.25    0.75            9.25    7.00
> 9.50  1.77            9.50    0.38            9.50    9.57
> 9.75  6.15            9.75    2.85            9.75    7.57
> 10.00 3.69            10.00   1.54            10.00   7.21
> 10.25 2.00            10.25   4.00            10.25   3.36
> 10.50 5.17            10.50   5.54            10.50   5.36
> 10.75 8.92            10.75   4.92            10.75   5.71
```

Comment: What substantive question would such a conclusion answer? Any reasonable test will conclude these curves differ among each other, but so what?  What you might want to be thinking about instead is how best to use these data to characterize what you want to know about the bird behaviors.  Have you plotted these data to enable a visual comparison?  That would be an excellent initial step in your analysis.

Comment: This question is only small part of the project. The aim of the project – is revealing the dependence of distribution of  Black Vultures (a bird species) in a soaring flight from  the  parameters superficial and parameters meteorological.

Comment: Yes, I have already created different plots with these (and other) data. I used this data, for example, to analyze how change meteorological parameters and birds activity during a day .
Now (for obtain these conclusions) I want to determine is the “type of activity” (the shape of this graph) of this birds different in each month or quasi identical? The same question I will use for compare “type of activity” on different landscape (urban, natural, mixed). A simple example (graph of activity for some month, without other data):

Comment: https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/10801618_995643917127882_5271235973091648468_n.jpg?oh=197eec09613197f338ee12dff02c2eb5&oe=54DFF8A5&__gda__=1427484793_acf67e6cc5f0bfb068c8bced67617384

Comment: Now I am not very strong  in Statistics (a beginner), and need to find a proper test for this task, and then – find how to do this test correctly (in R).

Comment: On another forum I got an advice to use in R  “Handling and Analyzing Spatio-Temporal Data”: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html
It has some special packages for the analysis of animal movements: “Moving objects, trajectories” (that seems more suitable for my task ) and ”Point patterns” that also could be acceptable.

Comment: And now I don’t know what is the best for my case.
I didn’t receive the  answer for my previous question about principle of work anova and linear modelling for my task. And also have advice about different methods. So, I don't know what to do.
Bat maybe I should ask a new question about it.

Comment: I would focus on tests of the distribution, such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov, ref http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35g.htm

Answer (score 1):

Following may be helpful:

You need to arrange data as follows:

```
Hours value month 
8.25  0.00  RJan
8.50  0.00  RJan
8.75  0.00  RJan
9.00  3.75  RJan
9.25  1.54  RJan
9.50  1.77  RJan
9.75  6.15  RJan
10.00 3.69  RJan
10.25 2.00  RJan
10.50 5.17  RJan
10.75 8.92  RJan
8.25    0.00  RJul
8.50    0.00  RJul
8.75    0.00  RJul
9.00    0.11  RJul
9.25    0.75  RJul
9.50    0.38  RJul
9.75    2.85  RJul
10.00   1.54  RJul
10.25   4.00  RJul
10.50   5.54  RJul
10.75   4.92  RJul
8.25    0.00  RSep
8.50    1.38  RSep
8.75    2.23  RSep
9.00    4.15  RSep
9.25    7.00  RSep
9.50    9.57  RSep
9.75    7.57  RSep
10.00   7.21  RSep
10.25   3.36  RSep
10.50   5.36  RSep
10.75   5.71  RSep
```

Then apply linear modelling or anova:

```
> summary(aov(value~month+Hours, data=ddf))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
month        2  51.75   25.87   7.527  0.00233
Hours        1 114.10  114.10  33.191 3.07e-06
Residuals   29  99.69    3.44                 
> 
> summary(aov(value~month*Hours, data=ddf))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)
month        2  51.75   25.87   7.155  0.00321
Hours        1 114.10  114.10  31.554 5.83e-06
month:Hours  2   2.06    1.03   0.285  0.75442
Residuals   27  97.63    3.62                 
> 
> summary(lm(value~month+Hours, data=ddf))

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ month + Hours, data = ddf)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2713 -1.2291 -0.1811  1.1136  4.7027 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -19.3449     3.9184  -4.937 3.02e-05
monthRJul    -1.1727     0.7906  -1.483    0.149
monthRSep     1.8682     0.7906   2.363    0.025
Hours         2.3520     0.4082   5.761 3.07e-06

Residual standard error: 1.854 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6246,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5857 
F-statistic: 16.08 on 3 and 29 DF,  p-value: 2.403e-06

> summary(lm(value~month*Hours, data=ddf))

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ month * Hours, data = ddf)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0655 -1.2291 -0.2438  1.0700  4.7027 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     -23.1760     6.9134  -3.352 0.002383
monthRJul         2.9900     9.7770   0.306 0.762089
monthRSep         9.1987     9.7770   0.941 0.355124
Hours             2.7553     0.7252   3.799 0.000751
monthRJul:Hours  -0.4382     1.0256  -0.427 0.672595
monthRSep:Hours  -0.7716     1.0256  -0.752 0.458343

Residual standard error: 1.902 on 27 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6323,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5642 
F-statistic: 9.287 on 5 and 27 DF,  p-value: 3.093e-05
```

I think the last method will be most appropriate here.

Comment: I didn't understand the logic of these  tests  for my task. Could you explain it a bit?  The first one  (anova) for example. You realized  the test by two steps:  1) summary(aov(value~month+Hours, data=ddf)) and 2) summary(aov(value~month*Hours, data=ddf))
( with "+Hours" and "*Hours")
But each step has its own result (show that Pr <  Signif. codes, i.e. that  these graphs have a statistically significant difference (am I right ?)
But what result I have to use in the final text  or picture? 
I suppose that the Linear modelling (lm) has the same logic (it also has two steps).